# Mathematica: Generate many different plots from set of defined variables (lists) using for-loop

Tags: for-loop, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I tried to set up a loop to plot many different variables in different plots.
vars is a list containing the lists to be plotted. vars1 contains the descriptions for the axes. If I use

```
ListLinePlot[{vars[[1]]}, AxesLabel -> {"t", vars1[[1]]}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRange -> Max[vars[[1]]]]
```

a plot is drawn. Included in a loop it does not draw anything

```
    For[a := 1, a < Length[vars], a++,
 ListLinePlot[{vars[[a]]}, AxesLabel -> {"t", vars1[[a]]}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRange -> Max[vars[[a]]]]
 ]
```

Can anyone explain to me why the loop does not work and how to make it work, please?

Comment: Try wrapping a Print[] around your ListLinePlot. Five or ten years ago they changed the default behavior of the plots to not automatically have a side effect of displaying the plot. Putting that inside Print[] should give you your plots.

Comment: try `Table` instead of `For`

Comment: Print[] made it, thanks a lot!